# Connect / disconnect unknown postfix log

Tags: linux, postfix

After analyzing the postfix logs on my server I noticed the following message :

```
Sep  4 15:12:50 vps66698 postfix/smtpd[25401]: connect from unknown[195.22.126.189]
Sep  4 15:12:50 vps66698 postfix/smtpd[25401]: disconnect from unknown[195.22.126.189]
```

What is this message and how to improve the safety of my server ?

Thank you for your answers

Mickael

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text; copy and paste from the terminal into the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @StephenHarris Hi, I've edit my question after your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally when a remote machine tries to connect to your postfix server, postfix will attempt to do a DNS lookup of the address and report that in the file

eg

```
connect from 66-220-155-155.outmail.facebook.com[66.220.155.155]
```

or

```
connect from mail-it0-x249.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c0b::249]
```

Now if the IP address can not be properly resolved to a name then it reports `unknown` instead:

eg

```
connect from unknown[42.119.145.220]
connect from unknown[192.3.220.210]
connect from unknown[39.52.115.55]
```

Now in your case the connection is from 195.22.126.189.  If we attempt to look that up we get DNS errors, and so `postfix` just reports `unknown`.

Seeing "connect/disconnect" sequences for servers is normal on the internet; it could be spammers, botnots, misconfigured servers, scanning tools... My personal server that just handles mail for me saw 10 of these in the past 4 hours.

Comment: So it is not an attack ?

Comment: Not specifically, no.  Just "internet noise".  Every server on the internet running an SMTP server will see lines like this.

Comment: ok. your answer reassures me because before posting my question I thought banish the IP appears in the logs with ' iptables ' .